# GitHub CI - Docker .env file not found

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, github-actions, github-ci

I want to deploy my Next.JS app with Docker and GitHub CI. The actions is performing as wanted, but the `.env.production` file does not seem to be found when referencing it in the Dockerfile.

I also tried renaming it to .env or any other filename, I tried using another path like /app/.env.production and trying different versions of "SpicyPizza/create-envfile". The .env.production file is **not** ignored in .dockerignore or .gitignore.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cat .env.production && yarn global add pnpm && SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION=1 pnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cat .env.production && yarn global add pnpm && SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION=1 pnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is my current config:

```
name: Docker Image CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
jobs:
build:
environment: production
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Check out the repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

  - name: Create .env file
    uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v2
    with:
      envkey_EMAIL_SERVER: ${{vars.EMAIL_SERVER}}
      envkey_EMAIL_FROM: ${{vars.EMAIL_FROM}}
      envkey_EMAIL_TO: ${{vars.EMAIL_TO}}
      envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY: ${{vars.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}}
      envkey_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}}
      file_name: .env.production

  - name: Build and push Docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
    with:
      push: true
      tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPO }}:latest
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
##### DEPENDENCIES
FROM node:20-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat openssl1.1-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i

##### BUILDER
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN cat .env.production && yarn global add pnpm && SKIP_ENV_VALIDATION=1 pnpm run build

##### RUNNER
FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

USER root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.mjs ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs .env.production ./


USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I am slowly loosing my mind as I have been searching the error for hours. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker/build-push-action` action requires you to tell it, if you want to use a context.

So your action needs this addition in the build section:

```yaml
    - name: Build and push Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
        context: .
```

You can see the difference.
Build without `context`: https://github.com/RiRa12621/so-test-repo/actions/runs/5818894961/job/15776209523#step:5:158

Build with context: https://github.com/RiRa12621/so-test-repo/actions/runs/5818912126/job/15776262227#step:5:162

(My test builds are obviously still failing because I didn't check in any node files but that shouldn't matter to solve your problem.)

Comment: Wow, amazing! I did not think that this line would make a difference, since I assumed the default context would be set to that already. I also want to point out that a part of my problem was a current issue in the Next.JS version, causing environment variables to not be loaded during execution (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53367)